# React Native How to get user friends that not installed my app and send the invitation

Tags: android, ios, facebook-graph-api, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

So I am using [react-native-fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) in my app. I want my app to have functionality to invite user facebook friends to use my app. That functionality will be in card that show user friends profile picture and name, and a button that can be used to invite that friend. My app is not a game.

My first question is how can I get all user friends that not using my app and using `react-native-fbsdk` for invitation?

So far I know that facebook has two API to do this `taggable_friends` and `invitable_friends`.

`taggable_friends` is used when user need to do post and tag his friend (I think this not what I looking for, cause all I want is user press the button and the invitation will imediately send to his friend)

`invitable_friends` is use for game, but for non game app, I can use message dialog

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq/

> For apps which are not games, or for apps without a Canvas presence,
>   use our other products such as the Message Dialog on iOS and Android,
>   Send Dialog for the Web or the Share Dialog on iOS, Android, Web.
>   These products let a person easily select the friends they want to
>   message or share with.

So the second question is how I can use this message dialog inside my `react-native` app?

note: `react-native-fbsdk` has `FBAppInviteDialog`, is it relevant to this question?